# Oauth on iOS for Facebook/GitHub/Twitter/etc. through WebView/WebKit

Tags: ios, swift, macos, oauth

So it turns out that, for Facebook and Twitter at least, you can't do OAuth on iOS without using their SDK. I'm wondering though if it would be possible to do an OAuth flow through the web, using either WebView or WebKit, inside an iOS app. That way you can capture the appropriate session/token data through the WebKit instance embedded in the iOS app, and then login using OAuth on iOS would work without the SDKs.

Wondering if anything like that would be possible. It looks like GitHub doesn't even have an OAuth flow on iOS, even though they have one for the web. So being able to handle this would mean logging in through that on iOS.